# What is causing low water pressure in shower but not elsewhere?

Tags: plumbing, shower, water-pressure

We have recently moved in to a 1930s house and are renovating the downstairs. We have just installed a large boiler and hot water tank. The bath has 2 separate taps (faucets) and both have about 18L/min of flow.

The shower in the same room only has 11L/min (measured by unscrewing the main shower head) regardless of temperature (and the same for the identical shower in the en-suite next door). Both have 2 shower heads (one fixed and one hand held) and when I switch on both at the same time I don't see a noticeable drop in pressure and perhaps get 14L a minute which to me implies the shower's mixer is to blame.

The shower is a Crosswater DL2000RC.
My theory was that someone had reduced the pressure to accommodate two
showers on the old boiler but I no longer have such a constraint.

I have tried loosening the red screws a bit which didn't seem to make a
difference. Should it? What do they do? how far can I unscrew them? do they stop or do they
completely come loose?

I note that the dials to enable each shower theoretically have pressure adjustment in normal
operation via twisting them, however turning my handles has limited effect either way.

Any other ideas?

[image]

[instructions](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://crosswateruksouth.blob.core.windows.net/web/1/product-variant-files/dial-kai-17/dl2000rc-installation.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiWh56jurCCAxVoQEEAHdwTAAUQFnoECCMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2E0XH_PFLG0BmsvTYqy4qD)

Comment: Open up the things you marked with a red dot in your image and check if the filter is dirty. Be sure and lightly grease the seals with silicone grease when you put it back.

Answer (score 0):

There is a flow limiter in the head of the shower units.  I suggest removing the head and testing the flow.  If it improves then you know it is the shower head rate limiter.

I don't know that opening the integral shutoff at the shower valve will actually improve flow (possibly if it was used to restrict flow).

Comment: I have updated my question to clarify that the measurement was taken without the shower head. Any other ideas?